# Two JPanels overlapping?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jpanel, overlap

This is the code I'm dealing with: http://pastie.org/1501054 When you run this, for some reason, the two panels overlap. Why is this so? Any way I can fix it?

The ActionListener that is provided as an argument is irrelevant to this part of the program.

Also, where can I find a good swing tutorial that uses Eclipse?

Comment: Post the code in the forum. Include the main() method so we can execute the code.

Comment: Is the warning label supposed to be above both the labels and text fields?

Answer (score 0):

When you say you want a good swing tutorial for eclipse, do you want a GUI builder or a tutorial on Swing? Swing is all about layouts. Once you get that down, it's a piece of cake. Just start with flow layouts.
If you want a GUI builder, use Netbeans. It's incredible!

As for the overlap, it's not an overlap, but an overwrite. You can only have one panel in `BorderLayout.CENTER`, the default location.
If you want them side by side, do `getContentPane().setLayout(new FlowLayout());`
Or just `add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH)`

Comment: I want them one after another.

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure what you want the final result to look like, here's a few of my suggestions.

In the snippet where you add the warning panel to the JFrame

```
warningPanel.add(warningLabel);
contentPane.add(warningPanel);
pack();
```

contentPane being the container returned by JFrame.getContentPane()

JFrames by default use the [BorderLayout](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html), and so,

`contentPane.add(<someComponent>)`

is identical to

`contentPane.add(<someComponent>, BorderLayout.CENTER)`

You also add the mainPanel the same way, and you can't have two components with the same constraints, so instead set the warningPanel to `BorderLayout.NORTH`

`contentPane.add(warningPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH)`

And also remove the call to pack() in that code snippet, since you call it later on in your code.

Hope this helps.

---

PS

As for GUI building in Eclipse, this previous question on [Eclipse GUI Builder plugins](https://stackoverflow.com/q/942696/568406) maybe of use. I can't speak for tutorials on using Swing in Eclipse, but a quick google search digs up [this tutorial using the Eclipse Visual Editor project](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/opensource/library/os-ecvisual/)

Answer (score 0):

I am not seeing overlapping panes when I run your code. I wonder if you can post a screenshot of the effect that you see.

As for tutorials in Eclipse. I would suggest using [Windows Builder pro](http://code.google.com/javadevtools/wbpro/) in Eclipse for building Java GUI. This is an excellent product (free) and very good documentation on the site.

Answer (score 0):

Yes I see the warning label is over lapping the first row

That is because You didnt specify the layout for your contentpane.
Heres how you fix it

```
contentPane.setLayout(new GridLayout(2,1));
```

add this line under

```
Container contentPane = getContentPane();
```

and I think you should change your warning panel to gridlayout 1 and 1 not 0 and 1 because you still have 1 row and 1 column